# How to copy parquet file and overwrite the old one on HDFS

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs, parquet

My question is suppose we have two parquet files on HDFS: file1.parquet, and file2.parquet in different paths, and I want to copy file1.parquet to replace file2.parquet.

I used the command `hdfs dfs -cp -f /path1/file1.parquet /path2/file2.parqet`, there was not error thrown, but the file2.parquet was not changed at all. I have to delete file2.parquet first and then copy file1.parquet.

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: Because you are forcefully putting file1 content to file2.

Comment: There must be something wrong. It does overwrite correctly. There is nothing wrong in command.

Comment: I do want to put file1 content to file2, and still name the file as file2.

Answer (score 2):

Check below commands.

```
hdfs dfs -cp -f /path1/file1.parquet /path2/file2.parqet // Overwitten file1 content in file2 content.
hdfs dfs -mv /path2/file2.parquet /path2/file1.parqet // For rename file from file2.parqet to file1.parqet
```